# remove white block of text

Tags: iphone

I used codes below to display numbers on UITableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   



    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    TDBadgedCell *cell = [[[TDBadgedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];



    [cell setText:[ NSMutableString  stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[aArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]]] ;


    [cell  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


    return cell;



}
```

[image]

but the text of numbers have white block on background

how to remove these white blocks?

Welcome any comment

Comment: TDBadgedCell is your custom class right ?

Answer (score 1):

try `[cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`

and [cell setText:] is deprecated,
use [cell.textLabel setText:]

Comment: same result, white block still display

Comment: i think not helped because you use custom cell TDBadgedCell, I don't know how it implemented.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom UITableViewCell, TDBadgedCell, you are probably adding a UILabel to the cell.  Your setText method is probably setting the UILabel text.  For this UILabel, set it's background color to clear like others have suggested.

You can set the UILabel background color to clear one time your initWithStyle: reuseIdentifier: method.